# How to plot this kind of bar using whatever plot tools?

Tags: graphing-functions

I want to plot this kind of figure to show the progress of an event. The highlighted parts show detected instances [(Here's an example of what I want to plot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vXid.png). As you can see, there're in total 3 models and one ground truth, and I want to compare their performances. Do you know any tool that can help me plot this kind of bar-like figure?

[Here's another example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SV8Y7.png)

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange/ That said, I'm voting to close this question   because it's not about mathematics. Any spreadsheet will do this. If you are looking for something animated you will have to ask at stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Mathematica*:

```
PairedBarChart[{4, 0, 3, 6, 5, 1}, {4, 0, 3, 6, 5, 1},
 BarSpacing -> {0, 0, 0},
 ChartStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue, Orange, Purple, Black, Yellow}]
```

[image]

(Includes $0$ and $1$.)

Comment: Thanks David. But I probably need more than that. What I have is a series of data, some numbers are 1, others are 0. The distribution can be dispersed. Like I showed in link 2.